# Spacy import error: cannot import name 'COMBINING_DIACRITICS' from 'spacy.lang.char_classes'

Tags: python, pip, nlp, spacy, pydantic

When I try importing the NLP library 'Spacy' using `import spacy` I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'COMBINING_DIACRITICS' from 'spacy.lang.char_classes'
```

Here are my versions:

```
spacy==3.7.2
spacy-legacy==3.0.12

thinc==8.2.2

pydantic==1.8.2
pydantic_core==2.14.6

python version - 3.9.18
```

I tried installing, uninstalling Spacy, Upgrading the library & all the other common checks. Where is the issue?

Complete error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_33180\572880994.py in 
----> 1 import spacy

c:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in 
     11 from thinc.api import Config, prefer_gpu, require_cpu, require_gpu  # noqa: F401
     12 
---> 13 from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
     14 from . import util
     15 from .about import __version__  # noqa: F401

c:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py in 
----> 1 from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
      2 from .dep_parser import DependencyParser
      3 from .edit_tree_lemmatizer import EditTreeLemmatizer
      4 from .entity_linker import EntityLinker
      5 from .entityruler import EntityRuler

c:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\attributeruler.py in 
      6 from .. import util
      7 from ..errors import Errors
----> 8 from ..language import Language
      9 from ..matcher import Matcher
     10 from ..scorer import Scorer
...
      3     ALPHA_LOWER,
      4     ALPHA_UPPER,
      5     COMBINING_DIACRITICS,

ImportError: cannot import name 'COMBINING_DIACRITICS' from 'spacy.lang.char_classes' (c:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\lang\char_classes.py)
```

Comment: please provide the full error message

Comment: I've updated my question with the complete error message.

Comment: have you tried using virtual env?

Comment: No, I was using the base environment. Thanks for the suggestion. I created a new environment & the error is gone.

Comment: That great ! I will add it as answer to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new enviroments and install `scipy`, you can use the following command:

```
conda create -n myenv
```

Activate `myenv`:

```
conda activate myenv
```

install `scipy` check the [instalation](https://spacy.io/usage) page:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Then you can use `scipy`.